# Procedimentos que chama outros procedimentos em estrutura de dados

Tags: estrutura-de-dados

Na execução de um programa a **XXXX** pode ser usada na chamada de procedimentos, para armazenar o endereço de retorno (e os parâmetros reais). A medida que procedimentos chamam outros procedimentos, mais e mais endereços de retorno devem ser guardados. Estes são retirados da estrutura à medida que os procedimentos chegam ao seu fim.

XXXX pode ser:

- Pilha
- Lista
- Fila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se vai colocando um elemento em cima do outro e os elementos só podem sair de cima pra baixo, ou seja é um LIFO (Last in First Out) ou UEPS (Último que Entra, Primeiro que Sai), é uma pilha.

De fato [é como a memória costuma funcionar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

[Um exemplo em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8972/101).