# Filas (queues) são úteis no Node.js, que é assíncrono?

Tags: node.js, assincronismo, fila

Sei que em linguagens como o PHP, filas (*queues*) são muito usadas para realizar ações mais "pesadas", como o envio de uma série de e-mails e afins.

Por isso, levando em conta a natureza assíncrona do Node.js, esse tipo de abordagem é recomendada nesse ambiente?

Por exemplo: eu preciso de enviar múltiplos e-mails. Devo, então, procurar utilizar algum sistema de filas, ou posso deixar o *event-loop* nativo resolver essas tarefas para mim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filas não são o que parece que acha que é (em mecanismo sofisticado). Fila é apenas uma estrutura de dados muito parecida com uma lista sendo que usa o que se chamar FIFO (First In First Out) ou em português PEPS (Primeiro a Entrar, Primeiro a Sair). Ele se opõe à [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8972/101) que é LIFO/UEPS (Último a Entrar, Primeiro a Sair). Então, sim, esta estrutura de dados é útil para várias coisas e assincronismo nada tem a ver com isso.

Filas são usadas para inúmeras coisas. Pode ser usada para criar uma coleção de ações padronizadas como envio de e-mails, colocando todas mensagens que devem ser enviadas e o sistema sabe que por usar uma fila deve pegar os primeiros que entraram nesta fila. É possível criar sistemas mais sofisticados que permita que a fila vá recebendo novos itens (pode ser um agendador que talvez esteja chamando de fila), que algum objeto receba uma notificação que tem um objeto novo ou que mudou o estado dela de vazia para contendo algum item, mas a fila em si é só a estrutura de dados.

Mesmo algo sofisticado precisa de uma estrutura de dados para armazenar o que deve ser processado em um algoritmo deste tipo, a estratégia de como processar é que determinará qual a melhor estrutura. Para o exemplo é improvável, mas não impossível que uma pilha seja interessante, em alguns casos uma fila com prioridade pode ser mais interessante.

Por outro lado esta é uma técnica que se usa quando se quer uma... fila! Então em qualquer tecnologia pode-se fazer isto sem fila, só diferencia o quanto cada um deixa mais difícil. Fila serve para organizar dados em uma certa ordem.

Inclusive o assincronismo não é mágico, é possível obtê-lo virtualmente em qualquer linguagem, algumas de forma mais fácil ou melhor que outras. Pode ser bem caótico fazer algo sem uma fila, mas pode ser que para seu caso seja suficiente, e se você tem assincronismo fácil e não exige maior controle e tem pouco volume, essa solução pode ser suficiente para atender sua demanda. Não para qualquer caso. Assincronismo serve para não bloquear a aplicação, só isso.

Na verdade eu fico curioso em entender porque o assincronismo poderia evitar esse uso já que eles são [ortogonais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101), por isso não há dicotomia entre eles. O máximo que pode acontecer é que a biblioteca da linguagem tenha um sistema de fila interno para gerenciar o trabalho e você não precisa saber disto. Novamente isto nada tem a ver com o assincronismo, ainda que os dois mecanismos possam estar juntos na biblioteca.

A questão que eu não sei responder é se o Node tem uma biblioteca própria que gere uma fila de ações que você determina, de forma interna e expõe só a API dela. Eu posso garantir que tem alguma biblioteca que faz isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).