# Duvida sobre pilha

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, stack

Em uma pilha, o primeiro elemento é definido como topo e o último elemento inserido como base da pilha.

Essa afirmação está incorreta né?

Comment: Por que você diria que é incorreta?

Comment: Por que o ultimo elemento a ser inserido, em uma pilha, ele continua sendo inserido pelo topo, não é? E não como base

Comment: Relacionados: [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-a-stack-e-heap), [Como funciona e se usa o Stack em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8972/como-funciona-e-se-usa-o-stack-em-c)

Answer (score 0):

Afirmação está incorreta. Pilha é uma estrutura LIFO, last in first out, ou seja o primeiro elemento seria a base e o ultimo o topo.

Pegue várias folhas e coloque uma em cima da outra, você formou uma pilha, onde não pode retirar a primeira inserida sem retirar a última inserida. Logo a primeira folha seria a base desta pilha e então a última folha seria o topo, a que pode ser retirada e usada.