# Como inverter uma string sem utilizar o método reverse c#

Tags: c#

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Texto Normal : {texto}");

string textoInvertido = new string(texto.Reverse().ToArray());

Console.WriteLine($"Texto Convertido : {textoInvertido}");
```

Comment: Aqui `texto.Reverse().ToArray()`  deveria ser `texto.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray()`,Veja o exemplo: https://ideone.com/S5xsj4 . Favor [edit] e corrigir o código da pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é dentro de um [laço for](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-for-statement) iterar do último a primeiro caractere da string e com o auxilio de um objeto da classe [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0) os acrescentar ao final da string em construção por meio do método [`StringBuilder.Append`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=net-6.0):

```cs
string s = "Stack Overflow";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();           //Instancia um objeto da classe StringBuilder.
//Itere último ao primeiro índice da string s em i... 
for(var i = s.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    sb.Append(s[i]);                              //...acrescente o caractere s[i] ao final do objeto StringBuilder.
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
//wolfrevO kcatS
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/S3lEEO)</sup>

Outra solução pode ser obtida com o uso de um pilha. Veja em [Como funciona e se usa o Stack em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8972/137387) que pilha é uma estrutura de dados do tipo sequencia LIFO(Last In First Out).
Com o auxilio da classe genérica [`System.Collections.Generic.Stack<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-6.0) empilhe os caracteres da string, converta a pilha em Array de caracteres com o método [`Stack<T>.ToArray`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1.toarray?view=net-6.0) e a partir desse array [instancie uma string](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-string-ctor(system-char())).

```cs
string s = "Stack Overflow";
//Instancie uma string formada pelo array de caracteres obtido da pilha de caracteres cujo o conteúdo seja os caracteres de s.
Console.WriteLine(new string((new Stack<char>(s)).ToArray()));
//wolfrevO kcatS
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/KVV4Pd)</sup>